# Build Dynamic Menu in VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm authoring a VSC plugin that on activation, I would like to make an XHR call and then populate a menu with the results of that XHR. It doesn't seem like there is a way to dynamically add menus to the status bar or dynamic items to the list of items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do that. All commands must be pre-defined in `package.json` because of its *declarative approach*.

You can however, mimic this behavior. To do this you must use the `vscode.window.showQuickPick` API, adding the items that you received from your XHR call. A good example of this *dynamic approach* is [MDTools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=seanmcbreen.MDTools).

Also, a sample code for you to start:

```ts
let items: vscode.QuickPickItem[] = [];
  
for (let index = 0; index < yourHXRResultItems.length; index++) {
  let item = yourHXRResultItems[index];
  items.push({ 
    label: item.name, 
    description: item.moreDetailedInfo});
}

vscode.window.showQuickPick(items).then(selection => {
  // the user canceled the selection
  if (!selection) {
    return;
  }

  // the user selected some item. You could use `selection.name` too
  switch (selection.description) {
    case "onItem": 
      doSomething();
      break;
    case "anotherItem": 
      doSomethingElse();
      break;
    //.....
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah that's ultimately what I ended up doing.

Comment: @alefragnani: can you explain where we should add above code in package.json?

Comment: @Amir You declare commands in `contributes\commands` section of package.json. You can get more information here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributescommands. Hope this helps.