# Can I interactively change the labels in the context menu? VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can I interactively change the labels in the context menu?
I do know how to display the menu.

[image: MyMenu]

The string set in the title of the command is displayed in the context menu, but I want to change it according to the situation.

Is there such a function in the API of the VSCode extension?

Comment: You can have 2 context items which call the same command and show / hide based on a condition (`when` clause - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_conditional-operators)

Comment: Hmmm.I should have been more detailed about what I wanted to do.I would like to display the value of Configuration set by the user on the menu label.
So, instead of displaying the title text set in package.json, I want the menu label to change just before the context menu is displayed.

Comment: The answer from the link you gave me almost solved the problem.
Ideally, it would have been a customization of the context menu, but I think it is the best solution within the limitations of the current API. [ [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586589/build-dynamic-menu-in-vscode-extension) ]